# How to copy data pointed by byte* to a buffer pointed by IntPtr? (C#)

Tags: c#, unsafe, intptr

In C#. I'm working with images obtained from unsafe context. I have an integer with the image size and image pixels pointed by a byte* variable. I would like to copy those pixels into a buffer pointed by an IntPtr. How can I do that?

```
byte* imgData;        // image data
uint uiDataSize;      // image size
...
IntPtr ptr;
buffer.GetPointer(out ptr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a framework method that will work.  [Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can copy memory into and out of an `IntPtr` buffer, but it doesn't work with pointers.

Instead you can P/Invoke the native [MoveMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which copies memory between two pointers.

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError=false)]
static extern void MoveMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, UIntPtr size);
...
byte* imgData;        // image data
uint uiDataSize;      // image size
...
IntPtr ptr;
buffer.GetPointer(out ptr);
MoveMemory(ptr, (IntPtr)imgData, (UIntPtr)uiDataSize);
```

Yes the `size` parameter of `MoveMemory` is `UIntPtr` not an `int` because the [`SIZE_T`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SIZE_T) used in the native code is 32 bits on 32 bit systems and 64 bits on 64 bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Runtime.Interopservice.Marshal.Copy`, if I remembered correctly. Check the function and you will know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.Runtime.Interopservice.Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

byte* imgData;        // image data
uint uiDataSize;      // image size
...
IntPtr ptr;
buffer.GetPointer(out ptr);
// Copy the unmanaged array to a managed array. 
byte[] managedArray = new byte[lengthOfData];
Marshal.Copy(imgData, managedArray, 0, lengthOfData);
```